# Symfony 4 bugged route

Tags: php, symfony, methods, action, symfony-routing

I was trying to create a route type "any" to allow both `get` and `post` but it did not work so I tried adding two routes to my route annotation like this

```
 /**
 * @Route("/news", name="newsSinglePOST", methods={"post"})
 * @Route("/news", name="newsSingleGET", methods={"get"})
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
```

That did not work either but then I tried deleting one but the route is now unusable, the controller does says something about a missing return statement and in my router I have the following line:

`newsGet                    ANY      ANY      ANY    /news`

to get my controller working again I had to change `/news` to `news2` so this route is now somehow unusable

I tried clearing the dev cache without success

So my question is how can I recover my route `/news` ?

Comment: You must uppercase the method names

Comment: Don't use two Annotations entry. The correct way is
`* @Route("/news", name="newsSingleGET", methods="GET|POST")`

Comment: @MarcosRegis your suggestion is in my opinion simpler and better than the one suggested below, post an answer and I'll accept

Comment: I made a test here and I was wrong. The way you did work on Symfony 4.1 using *Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;*
` * @Route("/news", name="newsSinglePOST", methods={"post"})` 
` * @Route("/news", name="newsSingleGET", methods={"get"})` 
When I ran `php bin/console debug:router` both routes are shown. 
Which version of Symfony?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/o6hp/organising-routes-within-symfony4-applications) and [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/7f0h/organising-routes-and-controllers-in-symfony-4-applications).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the `method` annotation like this ?

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * @Route("/news", name="news")
 * @Method("GET|POST")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try once I recover my route

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * @Route("/news", name="newsSinglePOST")
 * @Route("/news", name="newsSingleGET")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
```